# Trimming domain part from a variable containing a host name

Tags: bash

How can i use an variable in an ssh command in bash

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "what is your domain name"
read domain
```

How i want to add a variable named `sitename` that takes the string in variable domain put it in an ssh command and execute it and then store the result.

I tried the following and unfortunately none are working so far

```
sitename=`${domain} | sed 's/\.[^ ]*/ /g' ` 

sitename=$({domain} | sed 's/\.[^ ]*/ /g')

sitename=$(domain | sed 's/\.[^ ]*/ /g')
```

Comment: `sitename=$(echo "$domain" | sed '...')` should make it. Note you are currently doing `sitename=$(SOME_STRING | sed '...')`, which does not make sense.

Comment: @fedorqui thanks it worked but is there a better way of doing it without using `echo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current approaches are:

```
sitename=`${domain} | sed 's/\.[^ ]*/ /g' ` 

sitename=$({domain} | sed 's/\.[^ ]*/ /g')

sitename=$(domain | sed 's/\.[^ ]*/ /g')
```

if we emulate the behaviour once `$domain` variable is given to for example "mystring", this would be:

```
sitename=`mystring | sed 's/\.[^ ]*/ /g' ` 

sitename=$(mystring | sed 's/\.[^ ]*/ /g')

sitename=$(mystring | sed 's/\.[^ ]*/ /g')
```

So you can see it is not a valid *NIX command.

What you have to do is use either of these options:

```
sitename=$(echo "$domain" | sed 's/\.[^ ]*/ /g')

sitename=$(sed 's/\.[^ ]*/ /g' <<< "$domain")
```

---

This is regarding the usage of the variable. Regarding the change of the value itself (give first block of string up to the first dot `.`), then you can use [tripleee's good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25180602/1983854) with `${domain%%.*}`. Also, note that your sed command uses `/g`, which is not necessary because the substitution is done just once. Hence, `sed 's/\.[^ ]*//` suffices.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use the shell's built-in string substitution mechanism.

```
sitename=${domain%%.*}
```

The `%` modifier returns the value of `domain` with any match on the expression after it trimmed off.  It trims the shortest possible string; `%%` trims the longest possible match.  There is a similar operator `#` for trimming a prefix, and (in Bash) a general-purpose replacement operator `${variable/str/repl}`.

Comment: Note that the wildcard `.*` is not quite the same as the regex `\.[^ ]*` you were using.  Given the problem statement, I simply trim everything after the first dot.

Answer (score 2):

Use parameter expansion:

```
shopt -s extglob
sitename=${domain/.*([^ ])/ }
```